# How to store characters in string using C++

Tags: c++, string

```
size_t parameterStart_pos = str.find(searchIdentifier);
char sa = str.at(parameterStart_pos);
while (str.at(parameterStart_pos) != ';') {
     sa=str.at(parameterStart_pos);
     parameterStart_pos++;
}
```

This is the sample code in which it looks for identifier name and iterates over each *char* from that position until the end of line with delimiter *";"*

What I want to do is to store all characters from "parameterStart_pos" until it finds ";" in *string* to do further string operations. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy each character you pass onto in another string:

```
std::string result;

while (str.at(parameterStart_pos) != ';')
{
  result += str.at(parameterStart_pos);
  ++parameterStart_pos;
}
```

`result` now contain your string

Comment: Can you tell me if your str is an std::string or a c string,

Comment: Yes, its an std::string and thanks for your code .. it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code:

```
size_t parameterStart_pos = str.find(searchIdentifier);

char sa = str.at(parameterStart_pos);

string newStr = "";

while (str.at(parameterStart_pos)!=';'){

sa=str.at(parameterStart_pos);

newStr += sa;

parameterStart_pos++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1:take a string variable `std::string res`

2: con-cat  the char to the string.

> res.append(sa);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all characters from *parameterStart_pos* to *;* in a string *result*, you can do:

```
size_t parameterStart_pos = str.find(searchIdentifier);
size_t end = str.find(';');
std::string result{str,parameterStart_pos,end - parameterStart_pos};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handcraft copy code on your own. The C++ standard library has all you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string s1("1234567890,abcdefghijkl;mnopqrstuvwxyz");
    string s2;

    auto startpos = find(s1.begin(), s1.end(), ',');
    startpos++; // ignore the ","
    auto endpos = find(s1.begin(), s1.end(), ';');
    s2.resize(endpos-startpos);
    copy(startpos, endpos, s2.begin());

    cout << "s1" << s1 << '\n';
    cout << "s2" << s2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) using [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

Starting with a string looking something like this;

```
std::string s1 = "to skip over; p1 -a -b -c; p2 -d -e; junk chars";
```

---

You could do;

```
size_t start = s1.find("p1");
size_t len   = s1.find(';', start) - start;

std::string s2 = s1.substr(start, len);
```

Makes `s2` equal to  `'p1 -a -b -c'` and;

```
start = s1.find("p2");
len   = s1.find(';', start) - start;

std::string s3 = s1.substr(start, len);
```

Makes `s3` equal to `'p2 -d -e'`.

Then to grab the *leftover* `' junk chars'`

```
std::string leftover = s1.substr(start + len + 1);
```

Leaving you with:

```
s2 == "p1 -a -b -c"
s3 == "p2 -d -e"
leftover == " junk chars"
```

---

Another way could be to include [sstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) and use a `std::stringstream`

This does the same as the last example (with a small difference);

```
std::stringstream ss(s1);

std::getline(ss, leftover, ss.widen(';')); // to skip over;

std::getline(ss, s2, ss.widen(';'));

std::getline(ss, s3, ss.widen(';'));

std::getline(ss, leftover);
```

The difference being you are left with;

```
s2 == " p1 -a -b -c" // <--- has space
s3 == " p2 -d -e"    // <---- now!
leftover == " junk chars"
```